# How do I make a tie or slur shape in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to create a tie or slur shape that connects two music notes in GIMP. I've tried creating a straight line using the Path tool and curving it, but when I choose "Path to selection" I end up with a thick wedge shaped selection and not the thin crescent shape that I need. What's the correct way to create this shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Paths tool:

- Make a straight segment by clicking two points that will be the ends of the slur
- Ctrl-click in the middle to add a 3rd point and drag it laterally to bend the segment.
- Click on one end point, Ctrl-click on the other end point to close the curve with a straight segment
- Ctrl-click in the middle of the new segment add a 4th point and drag towards the other middle point.
- Select>From path and bucket-fill selection.

[image]